# GoPro Dual HERO 3D stereo system only compatible with HERO3+ Black Edition units?

Tags: video-recording, sync, stereo

I need to shoot stereo video in perfect sync. I realized that GoPro offers [Dual HERO System](http://gopro.com/camera-accessories/dual-hero-system) but they only list compatibility for HERO3+ Black Edition units. So I assume the currently selling cheaper HERO3 White Edition and HERO3+ Silver Edition models are not able to do frame synchronization for 3D even though they might have the same HW sync connector/socket as Black Edition on their bodies?

I do not need the waterproof dual enclosure, I can connect bare camera units just with cable (because I need wider lens baseline). My main goal is to get stereo video in perfect synchronization only.

Answer (score 2):

I probably could have done a quick google search before asking. HERO3+ Black Edition may be the only currently selling supported unit, but I found that following historical products are compatible with a "3D HERO System" (which may be different from "Dual HERO System"):

- HD HERO Original camera
- HD HERO2 camera

Dont know whether "3D HERO System" has different sync cable than current DUAL System. Also, a guy called "linuxluver" said on [this page](http://gopro.com/camera-accessories/3d-hero-system) that he is using his "Hero3 Silver cams for 3D content". I am not sure if he uses the sync cable or not.

Still, they list the [HERO3+ BE as the only compatible with "Dual HERO System"](http://gopro.com/support/articles/dual-hero-system-requirements).

Comment: The Dual Hero System is their new product for the Hero3+ Black. The 3D Hero System was for their Hero and Hero 2 cameras, while they don't sell the Hero and Hero 2 anymore they still sell the 3D rig for them, very similar rig, probably different hardware to sync them and also a lot cheaper http://gopro.com/camera-accessories/3d-hero-system

Though you will find Hero 1+2 cameras mostly only used nowadays.